# How to avoid retain cycle warning when a block try to set its self to nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm reading the source code of [SimpleAudioPlayer](https://github.com/owlcoding/SimpleAudioPlayer) and find that Xcode will raise a warning when `playBlock` try to set its self nil.

I don't know how to get rid of this warning, or must we set `playBlock` to nil?

```
- (void) playFiles:(NSArray*) filesList withCompletionBlock:(CompletionBlock) completion
{
    __block int idx = 0;
    __block void(^playBlock)();
    playBlock = ^() {
        if (idx >= filesList.count) {
            if (completion) {
                completion ( YES );
            }
            playBlock = nil; //Capturing 'playBlock' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle
            return ;
        }
        [self playFile:filesList[idx] withCompletionBlock:^(BOOL completed) {
            playBlock ();
        }];
        idx ++;
    };

    playBlock ();
}
```

Comment: why r u calling playBlock(); from inside playBlock()?

Comment: you can make __weak object... Something like `__weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;`  ,, in your case i dont think that you need to set playBlock to nil ever.

Comment: Declaring playBlock as __weak will lead to its releasing immediately after assigning, so this is not an option

Comment: @NikolayMamaev it can't be set nil if declaring as __weak

Comment: @AkshitZaveri it's not my code.I have the same question as you.

Comment: @AkshitZaveri This code changes the iteration (over the array) into a recursion. It is correct on a first view. It isn't easy to understand on the first up to the 239098324 view.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. @AminNegm-Awad

Answer (score 2):

No need to set `playBlock = nil;` neither declare it with `__block` modifier. Modified code (see below) compiled without warnings or errors.

```
- (void) playFiles:(NSArray*) filesList withCompletionBlock:(CompletionBlock) completion
{
    __block int idx = 0;
    void(^playBlock)();
    playBlock = ^() {
        if (idx >= filesList.count) {
            if (completion) {
                completion ( YES );
            }
            return ;
        }
        [self playFile:filesList[idx] withCompletionBlock:^(BOOL completed) {
            playBlock ();
        }];
        idx ++;
    };

    playBlock ();
}
```